# Is ChatGPT considered Ubuntu Third Party Software?

Tags: discussion

Is ChatGPT considered Ubuntu Third Party Software?

Are questions about using it on Ubuntu on-topic?

Comment: I would tend to doubt that such questions about ChatGPT have much of a place on Ask Ubuntu main site at the moment, although I certainly welcome the excellent question and answer on installing the 'offline' GPT-2 Output Detector.  But ChatGPT has been a hot topic on Ask Ubuntu Meta and doubtless will continue to be so for the foreseeable future...

Answer (score 8):

**You're not running ChatGPT**. Your browser handles input and output, but it's not running on Ubuntu. It's running in datacentres rented by OpenAI.

A question about it —in the way it exists at the time of writing— is *likely* off-topic **but** there probably are questions about it, its API and ways to develop and improve Ubuntu that do integrate its service that could be on-topic, so it's important to note that "likely" explicitly does not mean "always and forever more".

There are other AI packages that you can run locally, and getting them working would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Generally no, but possibly

If your question is simply about using ChatGPT itself in your browser and your OS happens to be Ubuntu, then no, it isn't on-topic anymore than asking for help with other web applications is (i.e., it would be off-topic). If you're having an issue using the web version that is Ubuntu-specific, I suppose that could be on-topic, but I'm having trouble imagining such a question.

If a user asks ChatGPT how to do something on Ubuntu, and then has trouble, and wants to ask what their mistake was/how to do it correctly, then I *think* that would be on topic (although bear in mind that that last statement is my opinion, and I don't have a policy/Meta post backing that up)

That said, a question about how to get it or related software running locally would be on topic. Of course, AFAIK, you can't run it locally, but I know we already have (at least) one well-received question asking how to get a ChatGPT detector running locally.

Comment: I agree - using web applications are generally not Ubuntu software, because it's neither specific to Ubuntu, nor is it a part of Ubuntu. If this was allowed, it would open the gates to questions about all sorts of websites with no relation to Ubuntu at all. There are other and better SE sites for these topics.